# With this approach on method injection and compared with constructor injection in Java

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have seen several frameworks that tend to use method injection, for example:

```
public abstract class MyClass {
    /** Create the class here */
    protected abstract Prototype createPrototype();

    public void doSomething() {
        createPrototype().foo();
    }
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        createPrototype().bar();
    }
}
```

And they may use anonymous inner classes to add custom functionality/create that your preferred object:

```
   new MyClass() {
      createPrototype() {
        return prototype;
      }
   }
```

And then others that favor constructor injection, for example guice.

Are there advantages over constructor injection, is it good practice to use method injection?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Your first example isn't method injection, and you haven't provided any context (sometimes one or the other is clearly better, and increasingly the fields are set directly through reflection).

Comment: I think constructor injection vs field injection is a more interesting question as they differ more widely in use case.

Comment: The first example is from the spring example on method injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some rare conditions where constructor-based dependency injection is not possible, however I think it is generally considered better to use constructor, rather than method, based DI because that way your object is initialised with everything ready to go, and if something is missing then you can catch that at all in one go at object construction. Also you typically don't want to mess with your dependencies after they are set, so throwing in a load of setters for them breaks encapsulation somewhat. What's the point of having a setter if you never want to use it?

Comment: There are no major issues or harm with using method injection?

Comment: @BerlinBrown Having read the question again I see you're referring to spring's lookup method-injection whereby spring used bytecode generation to create a factory method which returns prototype scoped beans, so that you can use it within a singleton scoped bean.  I don't know the competition (guice etc) well enough to offer comparisons. I'm not sure it makes sense to comapare it with constructor injection.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily talking about spring's lookup.  I did just use their example.   I was more curious in using the approach.  You gave good information.

Comment: @BerlinBrown Ok. Well I think the key thing is that in that example, the technique is used because otherwise it;s not possible to have a singleton bean which uses prototype scoped beans inside it. If there is a constructor oriented alternative to solve the sam problem, then I'm unaware of it. Cheers : )